QGIS - Create layout grid with lines at specified coordinates
I am using QGIS 3.34.7 (LTR), my project and layer CRS are EPSG 4326 (WGS84).
I have a need to create a 0.5 x 0.5 degree grid in a layout, one each of the x and y grid lines should intersect a specific point feature located at 1.14326, 53.12692 (lon/lat).
I have achieved this using the steps below but would like to know if there is a better method that I have missed. Possibly by utilizing the grid_number variable?

set up the appropriate grid intervals and then specified an offset that matches the coordinates of my point. This is grid one:


My grid lines intersect at the desired location (yellow highlight below):

However my first y grid line is at the specified offset which means it is more than 0.5 degrees from the bottom of the layout (yellow highlight below), the x grid lines are okay:


To workaround this I have configured a second grid, specifying a 0.5 degree y interval and a y offset of 51.127 degrees (first y grid line coordinate - 0.5). This is grid two. I've then manipulated the label text so that the two grid labels look okay.


Given that I do not need to correct the x grid lines in grid one, could this behavior be a bug?

It could be a bug, but because grids need to wrap, the behaviour is not always predictable. I agree that the x and y treatments are not consistent. You could try just using the part after the decimal as your offset (0.14326, 0.12692) - that might avoid the need for two grids.

Please report this issue on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues.

@Tom Brennan - using the decimal fraction part only in the offset resolves the issue. Removing the hundred thousand digit from the offset has worked on a layout using a projected coordinate system (British National Grid) e.g for 553797, 345232 use 53797, 45232
I hadn't appreciated that the grid should wrap, makes sense that this is a bug as Andrea Giudiceandrea has pointed out. Thanks both
Edit: added british national grid info

It is a bug. See the issue report at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/58386 and the proposed fix at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/58389.
